# Prove that $c*0=0$ in a vector space $V$, where $0$ is the additive identity and $c$ is a scalar.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

> Let $V$ be a vector space. Let $u$, $v$ be vectors in $V$, and let $c$ be a scalar. Using only the definition of a vector space, prove that $c*0=0$, where $0$ is the additive identity of $V$.

I keep on going back and forth with different methods, but they all feel that they have similar problems, like the one below.

Proof:

> We want to find that $c*0=0$. Add the additive inverse of $c*0$, $-c*0$, to both sides. Therefore, $c*0+(-c*0)=0+(-c*0)$. By the definition of an additive inverse, then $0=0+(-c*0)$. By definition of the additive identity, then $0=c*0$.

However, I feel like this is wrong, since I'm assuming that $c*0=0$ is true, but I don't know how else to approach this. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Troposphere I encourage you to answer the question, starting with what you've done here that no one else yet has: addressing the askers effort.  Then feel free to suggest an alternative.  I will upvote your answer if you answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in feeling that is wrong -- all your computation proves is that if $c\cdot 0=0$ then $-(c\cdot 0)=0$ too. But you already know that since $-0=0$.

The underlying *reason* why your computation doesn't lead anywhere is that you're not using *any* of the axioms that tell us how scalar multiplication must behave:

- $c\cdot(d\cdot v) = (cd)\cdot v$
- $(c+d)\cdot v = (c\cdot v)+(d\cdot v)$
- $c\cdot(v+w) = (c\cdot v)+(c\cdot w)$

The first two of these aren't of any obvious use in your situation because you don't know anything about the $c$ to the left of the dot. But the third one is promising because you do know that the thing to the *right* of the dot is, specifically, the zero vector, which you know some further properties of -- for example that $0+v=v$. Thus if you chose an arbitrary $v$ and use this identity you get
$$ c\cdot v = (c\cdot 0) + (c\cdot v) $$
You can now cancel $c\cdot v$ using known properties of vector addition and be left with $0=c\cdot 0$.

---

As an aside, you'll probably also want to distinguish more clearly between $(-c)\cdot 0$ and $-(c\cdot 0)$, until you have proved explicitly that they are the same thing (which you probably haven't yet if you're still only proving that $c\cdot 0=0$).

Comment: This was really helpful. So would it be right to then start from a property that we know, such as the $0+v=v$, and then working the way down through other properties of a vector space in order to get $c*0=0$? When I determine the additive inverse of $c*0$ then, should I distinguish it as $+c*(-0)$, since c is just a scalar?

Comment: @red: In general proofs (except indirect ones) always _start_ from facts you know and eventually each the desired conclusion. Starting from the claim you _want_, as you did in the question, is not the a of the proof (It can be useful for exploratory doodling, but that doodling is not part of the proof you eventually write down).

Comment: @red: The notation for "the additive inverse of $c\cdot 0$" is $-(c\cdot 0)$. There are various things this is _equal to_, such as $-0$ or $(-c)\cdot 0$ or for that matter $c\cdot(-0)$ or $0$ itself -- but that just means that the different calculations those other formulas specify happen to give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prove first that if $v\in V$ and $v+v=v$, then $v=0$.

Indeed, from $v=v+v$ we can deduce that
$$
-v+(v+v)=-v+v
$$
Thus, using the axioms for the negative and associativity
$$
(-v+v)+v=0
$$
so $0+v=0$ and therefore $v=0$ (using the axiom on $0$).

Now your proof:
$$
c0=c(0+0)=c0+c0
$$
and you're done.

This eliminates your confusion between $-(cx)$ and $(-c)x$, which is the source of your problems.

Similarly, $0v=(0+0)v=0v+0v$ and so $0v=0$.

Comment: @amWhy The OP writes “… but I don't know how else to approach this. Any advice is greatly appreciated”. Please, read the questions more carefully. Anyway, I added a comment.

Comment: I don't play those kind of games, but apparently, you find it convenient to blame someone who provided you with feedback, which has actually led to an improvement in your question.  Not everything is about you egreg.  Not a good habit to get into.

Comment: @amWhy There are different ways to approach somebody in order to ask them to improve an answer. Some are rude, others aren't. Your way is rude.

Comment: Your first comment to me is rather rude.  Teapot calling the kettle black, are you?  In any case, thanks for the improved answer.

Comment: I think this makes sense, but how exactly do I get $c*0+c*0=0$? Wouldn't I have to then add the additive inverse of $c*0$ to both sides in order to get $c*0=0$?

Comment: @red I get $c0+c0=c0$; by the initial lemma (that $v+v=v$ implies $v=0$), I can conclude that $c0=0$. Yes, at the end you add the additive inverse $-(c0)$ to either side, which is exactly what the lemma does.